# Updating list item change it list item id?

Tags: 2013

If i update or any user in our extra-net update a list item it is going to update the item id of the list item ?

If yes then how can i prevent it in list definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Update is not changes id or guid of SPListItem

Comment: thank you, list item has guid as well ??? O.o

Comment: The guid containes in SPListItem.UniqueId